# Convert letter to numeric number formatting in Excel using RegExp

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have an Excel sheet with given data in a cell. Want to convert letter numbering (e.g. a, c) or b))  to numeric number format(e.g. 1, 3) or 2))

### **Input Cell Data**

> Introduction and Basic wording
>   More lines here
>   a,c) A steps 1 and 3
>    - A sub-ste**p)** 1 of 1.
>    - A sub-step 2 of 1
>   ...
>   b) A step 2.
>    - A sub-step 1 of 2
>   d-g) A step 4 and 6
>   h) A step 5

**Note:**
Inside cell there are few character in given format **'p)'**

### **Output Cell Data**

> Introduction and Basic wording
>   More lines here
>   1,3) A steps 1 and 3
>    - A sub-step) 1 of 1.
>    - A sub-step 2 of 1
>   ...
>   2) A step 2.
>    - A sub-step 1 of 2
>   4-7) A step 4 and 6
>   8) A step 5

I used below RegExp to get the proper matching of letter numbering

```
(^|\n)((\w(?=\)|\,|\-)(\,|\-)){0,3}\w?\))
```

To replace it to numeric numbering format, I am using below code

```
Set colMataches = RE.Execute(strRegExp)  
For Each match In colMataches
    WScript.Echo "Found:"&match.Value
    Dim mt : mt = match.Value       'Output result: a,c), b)etc.
    Select Case mt
        ...
        Case "b)"
            sProc = RE.Replace(strRegExp, 2)
        ...
        Case Else
            WScript.Echo "Not Found"            
    End Select
```

As per my understanding:`Replace(expression , find , replacewith[ , start[ , count[ , compare]]])`
where **find** is the substring you want to replace & **replacewith** is the substring you want to replace with.
This usually work good when we are trying to find global matches for a specific value.e.g. want to replace a character like *'a'* or non character like *'-'* globally with a **single & specific** value like alphabet('b') or Numeric('1') or anything other than alphanumeric('@').
But i am failing to replace(a->1, b->2, c->3, d->4 etc) by use of **Select Case** statement. Is there a better way to do proper replacement?

Comment: first test your regular expression with a tester like here http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscriptexample.html

Comment: Regular Expression is correct as per below link [link]https://regex101.com/r/eC3dK5/5 Anything missing just let me know.

Comment: So the regex is working? What you need is help with the conversion?

Comment: Yes regex is working to filter out the desire characters. I am not sure whether i am using `Replace()` function correctly or not. Please let me know any other method to get the end result in VBScript.

Comment: I'd keep the closing parentheses out of the capture - you won't change it. Then check if a hyphen or comma is in `mt` if yes split. Next step is to get the ascii value since small a is 97 subtract 96 to get the number for the replacement.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing, but if you want to match only the bullet points like you do, you just can use `^(?:\w[),-]){0,3}\w?\)` pattern with `.Multiline = True` option. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJLRUg/1).

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for assisting me to make Regexp more handy. Please check the modified query as per request.

Comment: You cannot use `RegExp.Replace` like this. You just need to use  a simple `Replace()`.